# how to dynamically update topics of SinkConnector in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have written a Kafka Connect to consumer topics, but my topic will change at runtime, so I need reconfiguration the topics.

I know that use RESTful API can update topics is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Connect is intended to be run as a service, it also supports a REST API for managing connectors.
Only way to update this through REST API at run time :

PUT **/connectors/{name}/config** - to update the connector's configuration parameters at run time.

```
Request Json Object - config(map)

{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "20",
    "topics": "kafkaConnectTopic",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://smoketest:9000",
    "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hadoop/conf",
    "hadoop.home": "/etc/hadoop",
    "flush.size": "1000",
    "rotate.interval.ms": "100"
}

Response :

{
    "name": "hdfs-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "20",
        "topics": "kafkaConnectTopic",
        "hdfs.url": "hdfs://smoketest:9000",
        "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hadoop/conf",
        "hadoop.home": "/etc/hadoop",
        "flush.size": "1000",
        "rotate.interval.ms": "100"
    },
    "tasks": [
        { "connector": "hdfs-sink-connector", "task": 1 },
        { "connector": "hdfs-sink-connector", "task": 2 },
        { "connector": "hdfs-sink-connector", "task": 3 }
   ]
}
```

for further reading you can go through http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/userguide.html#connect-administration.

Comment: Thank you for response, I have looked the source code actually it can through modify a little slice code then can achieve this. but I'm not sure the modification whether will effect to other function.

Comment: Hi ,If you are interested , I am very glad to have a deep communication about kafka,I am now also looking deep into source code of kafka connect.My EMAIL: vico.wu1989@gmail.com.

Comment: Hi, the method you have provided basically restarts the connector with the new properties. Is there a way to update just one property in the sink connector? Let's say I just want to change the `"rotate.interval.ms":"50"` how should I proceed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a list of topics to consume from in the connector configuration if you know ahead of time the set of topics you will want to switch to.  Otherwise, the [the REST API](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/userguide.html#connect-administration) is the only way to update configurations on the fly.